# R function to order data.frames held in a list object

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sorting

I'm trying to find an elegant function to order data.frames held in a list object. I already know that lapply(df, function(x) x[with(x, order(var)), ]) works fine, but that seems way too complicated. I'm trying to use the "[" function, which works fine if I input the row numbers manually. But I'd like to use the row numbers generated by the order function, obviously.

```
df <- list(
    data.frame(name = c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"),   height = c(60, 58, 65, 55)),
    data.frame(name = c("Frank", "Tony", "Arthur", "Edward"), height = c(55, 65, 60, 50))
)

lapply(df, "[", c("height", "name"))

lapply(df, "[", c(3:1), )

order <- lapply(df, with, order(name))

order

lapply(df, with, order(name), "[")

lapply(df, with, "[", order(name), )

lapply(df, "[", with, order(name), )

Map("[", order , , df)
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. Also, generally how to correctly supply arguments to the "[" function when using the lapply or Map functions on a list object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other packages would simplify this. If you want to use base, you can extend what you were attempting with `Map()`:

```
order <- lapply(df, with, order(name))
Map("[", df, order, TRUE)
#pseudo translation: df[order, TRUE]
## where TRUE will repeat and select all columns of df
```

The simplest way with base is to move forward with what you suggest is too complicated. You could simplify with a premade function:

```
lapply(df, function(x) x[order(x[["name"]]), ])

#or
fx_reorder = function (x, col){
  x[order(x[[col]]), ]
}

lapply(df, fx_reorder, "name")

## or to accept multiple columns
fx_reorder2 = function(x, cols) {
  if (missing(cols)) cols = names(x)
  x[do.call("order", x[cols]), ]
}

lapply(df, fx_reorder2)
lapply(df, fx_reorder2, "name")
lapply(df, fx_reorder2, 1:2)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `library(data.table)` rather than `data.frame` then the solution is quite elegant.

We can convert your object to `data.table` using `lapply(df, setDT)`. Note this step won't be required if you create your objects as data.table in the first place, which would be a more typical workflow.

Then the ordering can be done using

```
lapply(df, setkey, 'name')

# [[1]]
#      name height
# 1: George     65
# 2:   John     60
# 3:   Paul     58
# 4:  Ringo     55
# 
# [[2]]
#      name height
# 1: Arthur     60
# 2: Edward     50
# 3:  Frank     55
# 4:   Tony     65
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `arrange` with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(df,  ~ .x %>% 
              arrange(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the `dplyr` package? You can put the `arrange` function inside `lapply`.

```
lapply(df, arrange, -height)
```

If you're not familiar with `dplyr` I would look into it. It sounds like your problem might be solvable with `bind_rows` and `group_by`.